# Capture file via stdin/cin with < and read to EOF

Tags: c++, c++17

**My main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   std::string filename;
   std::cin >> filename;
   std::ifstream inf(filename);
   std::string line;
   while(std::getline(inf, line)) {
         std::cout << line << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

**Trying to read:**

```
main < somefile.txt
```

I was old that when you write, `<` or `>` it's a directive for `stdout`/`stdin` (`cin`/`cout`). I want to read line by line, and check for EOF, in C++.

**EDIT:** Nothing really happens. Are there any C++ 20 recommendations for faster C++, I know C is normally faster.

**file.txt:**

```
300 55 12
56 99 -21
```

Comment: Nothing happens, even if the file under same directory contains content.

Comment: Currently, what your code appears to be doing is reading a line from stdin, and then opening a file with that name. Is that what you expect it to be doing?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I wrote it this way. But nothing comes out from the `cout` inside the `while`-loop.

Comment: @SuperStormer, `main < somefile.txt` I expect it to open that file or any file I pass to it like that. I tried, `argv[1]` but nothing.

Comment: @drescherjm, no it's under the same directory as the executable.

Comment: I tested it locally and it works. Does your file have a newline after the filename input?

Comment: @SuperStormer, how did you test it?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/3KH8xBYK `somefile.txt` itself contains a filename.

Comment: File redirection with < sends it directly to stdin, so you don't need to create a ifstream.

Comment: @SuperStormer, I know. But, I have to somehow keep track of EOF of the FILE?

Comment: You don't need to

Comment: @SuperStormer, I know. But, I want to know how to check EOF manually in C++ and break! Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File redirection with < sends it directly to stdin, so you don't need to create a `std::ifstream`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   std::string line;
   while(std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
         std::cout << line << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wrote code like this, the writing of code isn't a big issue mate. But, I am trying to figure out how I can check EOF and break.

Comment: Your code already does that right here: `while(std::getline(std::cin, line)) {` std::getline returns false when you hit the end of the file.

Comment: I know. But, `while(std::getline(std::cin, line) != std::cin::eof())` ?

Comment: The current code is correct and it will avoid this issue: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: getline returns false on eof